# How to open a saved .asm file in MARS on MacOS

Tags: macos, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am new to using MIPS and I can't find how to open a file that I saved. I saved a .asm file under my downloads folder but when I try to open a file in MARS and navigate to the same downloads folder, the .asm file does not appear.

I'm using MARS on MacOS.

Comment: Works for me; MARS's file selector box shows existing `.asm` files in a directory I browse to. I'm on x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux with `java --version` = openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20, and I'm using `java -jar Mars4_5.jar` to run it.

Comment: When you saved it, did you save it with MARS?

Answer (score 3):

As stated above, you need to allow Full Disk Access in your System Preferences in macOS. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469536/why-does-a-jar-file-have-no-permissions-to-read-from-disk-when-started-via-doubl) they mention that you need to search for 'JavaLauncher.app'. This is an issue due to macOS changes with security management.

To give Full Disk Access to JAR files on macOS:

1. Go to System Preferences.
2. Click on Security and Privacy.
3. Search for 'Full Disk Access'.
4. Click on the lock at the bottom left to be able to make changes.
5. Click on the '+' icon at the bottom left of the FDA panel and a Finder prompt will appear.
6. Go to System/Library/CoreServices/JavaLauncher.app
7. Select the JavaLauncher.app and click 'Open'

That's it. You should be able to access files through your Java application. This helped to fix my issue with MARS MIPS not saving files properly on my laptop. I constantly needed to save it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I had to allow access to finder directories for jar files. Mac didn't allow mars to initially access any of my directories.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by opening the jar file trough terminal. running this command:
java -jar Mars4_5.jar