# MARS simulator not working keeps opening a different file

Tags: macos, assembly, mars-simulator

I just downloaded MARS to write in assembly and something weird is happening.
When I try to run my file instead of running the file that I just coded it opens another random asm file from my computer and tries to run that one instead.
Have anyone saw that before?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to run it from the command line with the filename as an arg?  It works fine on my Linux desktop when I open files from the file menu.  Please describe *exactly* how you "try to run my file", with a `code block` for any relevant shell commands, and say what OS you're running it on.  (And I guess JVM version in case that matters.)  What directory is the "random" file in?  Literally random, or the same wrong file every time?  Basically this isn't a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterCordes hi so I have a macOs BigSur. java version "1.8.0_221" Then I downloaded the mars file, I double click on it. It open so I write my code, then I save the code and press run. Then it opens a random asm file that I have in my computer. It's very random because everytime opens a different one

Comment: Oh, MacOS.  There was a recent question about weird MARS behaviour on MacOS, [How to open a saved .asm file in MARS on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69021712).  Possibly another symptom of the same problem?  Also, you should [edit] your question with those additional details.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
My MARS program was saved in my Desktop and I had some asm files there. So for some reason that I am not sure about it, when I created a new code and run it would select one of those files in my desktop and run those instead.
But then when I moved my MARS program to a separate folder where it was by itself, my new asm code ran fine.

Answer (score 1):

One of my students just experienced this.  There was a Setting "Assemble all files in Directory" that was checked.  Uncheck that and it will only assemble the file you have open.

Comment: Oh, interesting, I assume that feature is intended to let you build a larger program out of multiple source files.  But yeah, could be pretty confusing to have that happen when you didn't expect!