# I hava mips , Logisim files In my desktop but I can’t open them

Tags: java, file, directory, mips

I’m working on some projects with my colleagues

when they send my files or when I save my files to use them again

[files on my Desktob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2427.png)

but when I try to open files from the app
I can't find any files on my desktop or any where on my Mac

[this is when I try to look for my files inside mips mars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfPrK.png)

I have tried uninstall  java , jdk and reinstall them
but nothing worked...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but opening the jar file from the terminal solved the issue.

Maybe the link is helpful.

[Why does a jar file have no permissions to read from disk when started via double-click - but not if started from the Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469536/why-does-a-jar-file-have-no-permissions-to-read-from-disk-when-started-via-doubl)