# Get folder content of sensitive folders on mac

Tags: java, macos, java-17

I have a java programm which used to work fine using Java 11. Lately we bumbed to Java 17 and Mac users have trouble to list their files of "sensitive" directories like the users Downloads or Documents directories. Other directories work fine.

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();
File[] files = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getFiles(new File(folder), !showHidden);
try {
  for (File file : files) {
    // here files is an empty iterable even tho files do exist in those folders
  }
  // ...
} // no error in its catch
```

What we tried:
I am aware, that there are security settings for files and directories having switches for those directories, but I checked and all permissions are granted there.

Which further conditions have to be met in ordner to be able to list the file content?

Further Details:

- The current app version was released around half a year after the previous version --> maybe some security changes took place meanwhile?
- The signing tool was changed from the deprecated altool to notarytool

Comment: maybe its "Full Disk Access" issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469536/why-does-a-jar-file-have-no-permissions-to-read-from-disk-when-started-via-doubl